# jQuery DatePicker add year to yearRange

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to add the year '9999' to my datepicker yearRange but nothing seems to work.  I want to do something like this:

```
$("#effective_date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "2002:2012,9999"
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It might not be possible using the jQuery api, but I'm sure there are ways of overriding the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this command :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange:'1950:2013'}).val();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this does what is being asked. When I'm wrong, can you explain how this adds an extra year?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to add year 9999 and with yearRange option then you have to increase the range from 2002 to 9999  like  yearRange: "2002:9999"

Comment: You like the answer below are not giving him the output he wants.

Comment: then can you clarify the question??

Comment: He wants the range to be from 2002 to 2012 AND the year "9999", which clearly is not what you offer him...

Answer (score 0):

Your comment:

> It might not be possible using the jQuery api, but I'm sure there are ways of overriding the javascript.

You can create your own plugin, if you want to use an existing plugin you need to use it's API, and this is impossible with the jQuery UI datepicker widget.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, there is probably a more elegant UI way to capture this non-date value but this can modify a year.  I'm not sure but I'd guess there are unintended consequences.

```
  var yearAdded = false;

  $(".ui-datepicker").on("mouseenter", function() {

    if (!yearAdded) {
      yearAdded = true;          
      var dropYear = $("select.ui-datepicker-year");
      dropYear.append("<option value='9999'>9999</option>");

    }

  });
```

Hope this helps.